# Invoke Windows Certificate Export Wizard .NET

Tags: c#, .net, security, certificate, x509

Does anyone know how to invoke/display the Windows Certificate Export Wizard Programmatically within C#.NET whilst providing an X509 Certificate?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to P/Invoke [CryptUIWizExport](http://CryptUIWizExport) from the Cryptui.dll.

Comment: Thats GregS, Do you have any ideas how to implement this?
The only information I can find on CryptUIWizExport so far is this on the MSDN site:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380395.aspx

My attempts to DLLImpport a wrapper for it so far have failed. Do you have any ideas on how to do it?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, but i do vote for program this wizard in C#. Look at X509Certificate2UI class and X509Certificate2.Export method. You will find there everything you need to export cert from store.

Comment: Hi Sinm, it does not look like it is possbile to invoke the Microsoft Certificate Export Wizard from those classes. :(